# Python pandas still nans after fillna()

Tags: python, pandas, nan, fillna

I have a DataFrame like this:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'open':[0, 1, 2, 3, 4], 'close':[1, 2, 2, 3, 2]})

print(df)

    open  close
0     0      1
1     1      2
2     2      2
3     3      3
4     4      2
```

Now I have this function to add a column 'candle_color':

```
def classify_color(df: pd.DataFrame):
    conditions = [df.close < df.open, df.close > df.open, df.close == df.open]
    choices    = ["Red", "Green", "Grey"]
    res = np.select(condlist=conditions, choicelist=choices)  # classify colors as Red/Green/Grey
    res = np.where(res == "Grey", np.nan, res)                # I don't want grey, so I replace it by nans
    res = pd.DataFrame({"C": res}).fillna(method="ffill")     # and forward fill the nans 
    res = res.C.values
    df['candle_color'] = res
```

Now if I apply the function and print the value counts, there are still nans..

```
classify_color(df=df)

print(df.candle_color.value_counts())

Green    2
nan      2
Red      1
Name: candle_color, dtype: int64
```

I really cannot see what I'm doing wrong here, as I'm assigning the result of fillna() to a variable (using inplace parameter with fillna and not assigning it to a variable gives the same output).
Help is much appreciated.

Comment: check if the 'nan' text is a String

Comment: @LucasBorges-Santos is right, the `np.nan` is cast to string in the `np.where`. Try with `None` instead of `np.nan`, it should work

Comment: Thank you very much @LucasBorges-Santos and Ben . I tried with **float("NaN")** aswell but it didn't work. It works as expected with **None** .